# NextJS getting url parameters returns empty at the begining

Tags: next.js

I want to get URL parameters at the begining of page, but firstly it returns empty, after a while

```
const rout = useRouter()
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('queries:')
    console.log(rout.query)
  }, [rout])
```

It returns {} for the first time, but after a render, It returns {'myparam': 'blabla'}

How can I get URL parameter without returning an empty result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router), the `useRouter` hook from `next/router` returns a prop `isReady`, which you can check.

> `isReady`: `boolean` - Whether the router fields are updated client-side
> and ready for use. Should only be used inside of useEffect methods and
> not for conditionally rendering on the server.

```
const rout = useRouter()
useEffect(() => {
  if (rout.isReady) {
    //rout.query will be ready here
  }
}, [rout])
```